# Last.fm won't return artist image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, last.fm

I'm trying to fetch and apply an artist image from Last.fm to an `ImageView`, but there isn't any image being returned. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
private void setLastFmArtistImage() {

    try {
        String imageurl = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getimages&artist="
                + URLEncoder.encode("Andrew Bird")
                + "&api_key="
                + APIKEY
                + "&limit=" + 1 + "&page=" + 1;
        InputStream in = null;

        Log.i("URL", imageurl);
        URL url = new URL(imageurl);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;

        httpConn.connect();

        in = httpConn.getInputStream();

        Bitmap bmpimg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        mArtistBackground.setImageBitmap(bmpimg);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: more detail is required... If an image isn't being returned.. then WHAT is being returned? These are basic debugging things you need to analyze.

Comment: Nothing is being returned, I mention that. Nothing changes.

Comment: no data is returned? if you go to that link does it return anything on a browser?

Comment: also, can you successfully change the image to a local image? `mArtistBackground.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.image));`

Comment: ofc stuff is returned.. but it's XML, not an image.

Comment: Yes, the ImageView works like it should. I can change it to anything local.

Comment: if its an XML then you have to parse the XML.. to retrieve the link :D

Comment: @adneal did u finish up your project yet? i have questions to ask..please tag me in ur response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API you're trying to use returns XML, **not** an image. You need to parse the response and select the appropriate image URL from the response.

The [API documentation](http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getImages) is pretty thorough, and viewing the sample response for everyones favorite artist, [Benny Hill](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getimages&artist=benny+hill&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026), will give you enough direction to find a suitable image to display.

**Edit**: For an example of the API you can look at the official [Last.fm client](https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/) - beware though, this is GPL3-licensed stuff and unless you feel like releasing your source you shouldn't be playing too much with the copy & paste.

**Edit (again)**: For an example that isn't *tainted* with GPL3, try this:

(The example uses [JSoup](http://jsoup.org), the friendly XML parser)

```
public List<LastFmImage> getLastFmImages(String artistName, int limit, int page) throws IOException {
    String apiUrl = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getimages&artist="
            + URLEncoder.encode(artistName)
            + "&api_key="
            + APIKEY
            + "&limit=" + limit + "&page=" + page;

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(apiUrl).timeout(20000).get();
    Elements images = doc.select("images");

    ArrayList<LastFmImage> result = new ArrayList<LastFmImage>();
    final int nbrOfImages = images.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < nbrOfImages; i++) {
        Element image = images.get(i);
        String title = image.select("title").first().text();
        Elements sizes = image.select("sizes").select("size");
        final int nbrOfSizes = sizes.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < nbrOfSizes; j++) {
            Element size = sizes.get(i);

            result.add(new LastFmImage(title, size.text(),
                    size.attr("name"),
                    Integer.parseInt(size.attr("width")),
                    Integer.parseInt(size.attr("height"))));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the LastFmImage class:

```
public class LastFmImage {
    public String mTitle;
    public String mUrl;
    public String mName;
    public int mWidth;
    public int mHeight;

    public LastFmImage(String title, String url, String name, int width, int height) {
        mTitle = title;
        mUrl = url;
        mName = name;
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been over the API docs, I actually have them open right now. I guess my problem is I'm not sure how to retrieve an image from the XML. Thanks for the tip. I'm actually trying to avoid copy and pasting. I actually want to learn how to do this.

Comment: Download the XML and analyze it and it should be pretty apparent.

Comment: @Jens Your example is extremely helpful. This is my first time parsing XML, so I couldn't have asked for more. Thank you, I appreciate it. I still don't quite grasp how I set my bitmap, but I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: Well, LastFmImage#mUrl will contain an URL you can actually load using your previous approach (fetch using HttpUrlConnection for instance).

Comment: Hey are there any legal issues involved with this??and the link you provided seems to be broken(of last fm documentation) that is the reasom i am asking this stupid question